# How can I fix flutter attrib

Tags: android, flutter

I downloaded and installed Flutter, I did everything right, but I keep running into a problem.

'attrib' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Follow this vid  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xj4cTEdnNo[fix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xj4cTEdnNo%5Bfix) Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1][1]

### Error on console

> exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header
> not found at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1567) at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1462) at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1469) at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.(ZipFile.java:1274) at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1237) at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:727)
> at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:844)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:247) at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:177) at
> java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:191) at
> org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214) at
> org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27) at
> org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74) at
> org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48) at
> org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48) at
> org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
> at
> org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

### Solution

1. Open finder and navigate to "/Users/[userName]"
2. To show hidden folders and files enter the command (if you use Mac) :

   ```
    cmd + shift + .
   ```
3. Enter in the folder ".gradle" and in this folder enter in folder "wrapper"
4. in wrapper folder remove the "dist" folder.

```html
 user
    |
   username
        |
     .gradle
        |
       wrapper
           |
         dist
            |
           *gradle
```

5. now, after remove "gradle" folders in the "dist" folder, in the terminal source project run

> flutter run -v

6. after that, run

> flutter run

Comment: I tried this way but didn't happen again